# Link in an email (DoCmd.SendObject)

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I generate an email in an application access in vba.
At the end I wish to put a hyperlink but the email is in raw and not in html. Do you have a solution?

```
DoCmd.SendObject , , , "adressmail@hotmail.com", "", "", " " & Types & " de " & Prenom & " " & Nom & " prend effet le " & Effet_au & "", "Madame, Monsieur," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "texte" &  **"LINK HERE"** & vbCrLf, True, ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the email to HTML by setting the format in the third parameter to 
`acFormatHTML`. This will mean that the entire email message will have to be in HTML however.